# Die Rolling Program php

Tags: php

I am in a class at IUPUI and I was given these instructions

1. In NetBeans, create a new PHP Web Page named index.php in the htdocs\I210\Lab04 folder.
2. Change the document title to “Statistical analysis of results from rolling a six‐sided die”;
3. At the very top of the page, add the following PHP code block and comments.

   ```
   <?php
   /*
    * Author: Your name
    * Date: Today’s date
    */
   ?>
   ```
4. Inside the body section, create a H2 heading that reads “Statistical analysis of results from rolling a
   six‐sided die” at the beginning of the page body.
5. Inside the PHP code block, create six variables to store the frequency of each side of the die. Choose
   your variable names wisely. For example, you may name them `$frequency1`, `$frequency2` ……
6. To simulate rolling a die, use the built‐in PHP function named `rand($min, $max)` to generate a
   random number between 1 and 6, 1 being Face 1, 2 being Face 2, and so on. The following statement
   generates a random number between 1 and 6 and stores it in the variable called `$face`. `$face = rand(1, 6);`
7. Use a conditional structure (IF or SWITCH) to increment frequency for each side of the die occurred.
   For example, if the value of `$face` is 1, increment $frequence1 by 1.
8. Use a loop structure (FOR, WHILE, or DO … WHILE) to repeatedly execute the PHP statements in the
   last two steps 5000 times.
9. Use a table to display die faces and their frequencies occurred during the 5000 times of rolls.
10. Below the table, add a refresh button.

    ```
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh" onclick="window.location.reload()" />
    ```
11. Add CSS to center everything on the page.
12. Thoroughly test your page. Clicking the “refresh” button should generate a new set of frequencies.
    Note: your frequencies could be different from mine."

I'm not asking for someone to do the work for me because I have most of the work done. I can't seem to figure out how to make my code loop 5000 times.
This is my code currently.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Statistical analysis of results from rolling a six‐sided die</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Statistical analysis of results from rolling a six‐sided die</h2>
        <?php
        $frequency1=0;
        $frequency2=0;
        $frequency3=0;
        $frequency4=0;
        $frequency5=0;
        $frequency6=0;
        $face = rand(1, 6);

if ($face==1)
{
++$frequency1;
}
else if ($face==2) {
    ++$frequency2;
}
else if ($face==3) {
    ++$frequency3;
}else if ($face==4) {
    ++$frequency4;
}else if ($face==5) {
    ++$frequency5;
}else if ($face==6) {
    ++$frequency6;
}
 echo "<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Face</th>
                <th>Frequency</th>
            </tr>";
            $face_num=6;
            $face_count=1; 
            while ($face_count<=$face_num) {
                    $frequency = ${'frequency' . $face_count};
                echo "<tr>
                        <td> $face_count </td>
                        <td> $frequency </td>
                     </tr>";

                $face_count++;
                }
            ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Refresh" onclick="window.location.reload()" />  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `for($i = 1; $i >= 5000; $i++) { your code...}` use the `for()` function to loop n times

Comment: You've got a `while` loop in there already that's doing the same thing. While your counter is less than 5000, do your code. Increment the counter inside the loop.

Comment: The while loop is for the table to display the right number of rolls and the frequencies of the rolls but I need the die rolls to increment.

Comment: I see you're using Pre-increments for your variables (`++$frequency1;` instead of the more usual post-increment `$frequency1++;`). While this is not incorrect, you should be careful regarding the final state of your variables when the loop ends. Check this just to err on the safe side http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: In future posts you should cut down your post to just the actual *question* about the problem you're having, and leave out copy/pasting the entire assignment. One thing that is *wildly* unpopular here is people asking us to do their homework, which is what yours looks like at first glance.

Comment: @Sammitch That is a fair point. Should I delete that part of the post now? or do you think it will be fine.

Comment: @MalleyBaker it couldn't hurt, but you've already got answers and no one's even left a snarky comment. At this point it doesn't really matter, tbh.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for()` loop to execute the code 5000 times.

```
$frequency = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

for($i = 1; $i <= 5000; $i++):
    $face = rand(0, 5); // index's start at 0
    ++$frequency[$face];
endfor;

for($i = 0; $i <= count($frequency) -1; $i++):
    $n = $i +1;
    echo "Frequency {$n} is equal to {$frequency[$i]}";
endfor;
```

for readability, I added the use of an array so its easier to manage in the future.

Running this code 10 times (not 5000) gives a result like this:

```
Frequency 1 is equal to 1
Frequency 2 is equal to 3
Frequency 3 is equal to 1
Frequency 4 is equal to 3
Frequency 5 is equal to 1
Frequency 6 is equal to 1
```

Note: You will need to implement this into your own view.

Here is an example of a view:

```
$frequency = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

echo "<table>";

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++):
    $face = rand(0, 5);
    ++$frequency[$face];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>";
    echo "Face";
    echo "</th>";
    echo "<th>";
    echo "Frequency";
    echo "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>";
    echo "{$face}";
    echo "</th>";
    echo "<th>";
    echo "{$frequency[$face]}";
    echo "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
endfor;

echo "</table>";
```

---

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have started implementing the for loop with my table already. I was basically insistent on using a while loop for some reason but the for loops are so much easier.

Comment: You could still use a while loop, just create a counter ie: `$count = 1; while($count++ <= 5000) { code here }` but yes, for loops are easier